# Autodesk Inventor add-in blocked

Tags: c#, certificate, add-in, autodesk-inventor

devs,

previously i started a project to make an Autodesk Inventor Add-in. i have written a piece of simple code on Autodesk's "simpleAddin" and have loaded it into the inventor, everything was fine.
then i tried to create add-in myself, i think everything in code is fine, while yet i have just copied the code from "simpleaddin", the only problem is that now inventor blocks the add-in to load automatically on start-up.
i have signed the .dll file and also tied to add the certificate to trusted certificates but it still shows this message :
"A certificate chain could not be built to a trusted root authority."

Answer (score 1):

it's solved now, 
1- as i mentioned you need to sign your assembly with a certificate, you can create a certificate yourself or get one from common certificate resellers.
2- while installing the add-in certificate must be copied to windows trusted certificates using certificate manager or CMD